# ef запрос не выполняется

Tags: .net, entity-framework

```
using (var db = new ServiceEntities())
{
    var temp = db.Cities.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Enabled);
}
```

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found. '

установил через nuget Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
в web.config
прописал

Answer (score 0):

нужно было добавить строку в web.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```